# My regex works on regex101 but doesn't work in python?

Tags: python, regex

So I need to match strings that are surrounded by `|`. So, the pattern should simply be `r"\|([^\|]*)\|"`, right? And yet:

```
>>> pattern = r"\|([^\|]*)\|"
>>> re.match(pattern, "|test|")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10341dd50>
>>> re.match(pattern, "  |test|")
>>> re.match(pattern, "asdf|test|")
>>> re.match(pattern, "asdf|test|1234")
>>> re.match(pattern, "|test|1234")
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x10341df30>
```

It's only matching on strings that begin with `|`? It works just fine on regex101 and this is python 2.7 if it matters. I'm probably just doing something dumb here so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`re.match` will want to match the string starting at the beginning. In your case, you just need the matching element, correct? In that case you can use something like `re.search` or `re.findall`, which will find that match anywhere in the string:

```
>>> re.search(pattern, "  |test|").group(0)
'|test|'

>>> re.findall(pattern, "  |test|")
['test']
```

Answer (score 9):

In order to reproduce code that runs on https://regex101.com/, you have to click on `Code Generator` on the left handside. This will show you what their website is using. From there you can play around with flags, or with the function you need from `re`.

Note:

- https://regex101.com/ uses `re.MULTILINE` as default flag
- https://regex101.com/ uses `re.finditer` as default method

```py
import re

regex = r"where"

test_str = "select * from table where t=3;"

matches = re.finditer(regex, test_str, re.MULTILINE)

for matchNum, match in enumerate(matches, start=1):

    print ("Match {matchNum} was found at {start}-{end}: {match}".format(matchNum = matchNum, start = match.start(), end = match.end(), match = match.group()))

    for groupNum in range(0, len(match.groups())):
        groupNum = groupNum + 1

        print ("Group {groupNum} found at {start}-{end}: {group}".format(groupNum = groupNum, start = match.start(groupNum), end = match.end(groupNum), group = match.group(groupNum)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the code generator comment

Answer (score 3):

Python offers two different primitive operations based on regular expressions: `re.match()` checks for a match only
at the beginning of the string, while `re.search()` checks for a match anywhere in the string (this is what Perl does
by default).

[Document](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match)

Comment: Thanks, I knew it had to be something that dumb on my part.

Comment: This part is very confusing, so they write a Document for it.